# ASP .NET Reference Web Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP .NET. I'm attempting to duplicate the example found [here](http://www.radpdf.com/demo/) for a simple in-browser PDF editor.

I made a blank ASP .NET project in Visual Studio and added _Default.aspx with the code from the link above:

**_Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="RadPdf" Namespace="RadPdf.Web.UI" TagPrefix="radPdf" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>RAD PDF Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <radpdf:pdfwebcontrol id="PdfWebControl1" runat="server" height="600px" width="100%" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**_Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using RadPdf.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get PDF as byte array from file (or database, browser upload, remote storage, etc)
            byte[] pdfData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\scotth\Desktopt-1 work order - Copy.pdf");

            //Load PDF byte array into RAD PDF
            this.PdfWebControl1.CreateDocument("Document Name", pdfData);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an error on the last line of _Default.aspx.cs:

```
this.PdfWebControl1.CreateDocument("Document Name", pdfData);
```

The error is:

> '_Default' does not contain a definition for 'PdfWebControl1' and no extension method 'PdfWebControl1' accepting a first argument of type '_Default' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why is this reference broken? It seems like it should be referencing this in _Default.aspx:

```
<radpdf:pdfwebcontrol id="PdfWebControl1" runat="server" height="600px" width="100%" />
```

Yet I have this error. How do I fix this reference? What is the standard way to reference these elements in ASP .NET? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Casing error: compare  `TagPrefix="radPdf"` with `<radpdf:pdfwebcontrol `

Comment: @rene ah interesting. I changed that, trying being consistent both ways, but the build error remains.

Comment: This is a duplicate of _many_ questions, try searching on that error. Use `CodeBehind` instead of `CodeFile` and make sure a member named `PdfWebControl1` is generated in the `.designer.cs` file.

Comment: @CodeCaster using `CodeBehind` fixed the build error. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Nah, leave it. I can't find a proper duplicate that properly explains the problem and the proposed fix. Maybe because the query "asp.net does not contain a definition for codefile site:stackoverflow.com" yields 8000 (!) results.